# FATAL EXCEPTION: main Unable to start activity java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, exception

E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.custmizedalertbox, PID: 20065
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.custmizedalertbox/com.example.custmizedalertbox.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3308)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3457)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at com.example.custmizedalertbox.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:29)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7906)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3283)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3457) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)

My app is crashed while running it.

How to fix this

Comment: You're trying to invoke a method setOnClickListener on an object which hasn't been properly setup up, here: _Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object_

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some code like this :-

```
Button btn = alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.someButton);
if (btn != null) { //Add null check here
  btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
   //some code
  });
}
```

so add null check here before setting setOnClickListener method to avoid any potential crash or just called it after above code line eg declare reference first and then try to invoke setOnClickListener.

Hope this helps!